# MsBuild shell open repeatly

Tags: windows, .net-framework

Since a few weeks I have a rather annoying problem: I have an MSBuild shell window that opens periodically (about once every 3 minutes) and closes immediately. There is no way to make it disappear. I tried to uninstall MSBuild but it's impossible, reinstall .NET Framework but I still have the same thing.

Here is the window displayed (a few milliseconds):
[image: window]

Comment: Run Process Monitor until it happens, then look at the process tree, what is the parent process?

Comment: No parent process for this process

Comment: That can’t be right.  Did you capture it being created in Process Monitor?

Comment: Parent PID is a process ID that don't exists apparently

Comment: So i've found the parent process, this is a process called "Rookie Sideloader VRP". I searched all my hard drives for a trace of this application and uninstalled everything. The problem seems to be solved.

Comment: @FlorianKamps you should enter this as an answer to your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, after a long research:

I've installed few months before a software called "Rookie Sideloader VRP", and this software often open a bash for checking update (I think)
I just uninstalled this soft and solved my problem by the time